# Refreshing extract in tableau from teradata throws error "Bad character in format or data"

Tags: sql, teradata, tableau-api

This is the custom sql query I am trying to submit when I am getting above error.

```sql
SELECT
  comp_type, 
  wm_wk_desc,
  wm_wk_beg_dt, 
  metric_id, 
  metric_nm,
  CAST(SUM(num) AS FLOAT) AS num,
  SUM(denom) AS denom,
  dim
FROM GE004_WM_AD_HOC.bs_scorecard_weekly
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,8
```

Comment: It is specifically saying bad character is in column num.

Comment: What is the data type of `num`?  If it's a `CHAR/VARCHAR` that stores numerical info, this could be the problem.

Comment: It is number only like denom.

Comment: If you run `SELECT CAST(num AS FLOAT) FROM GE004_WM_AD_HOC.bs_scorecard_weekly`, does that return without error?

Comment: Why cast as float if it's a number anyway?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, you are attempting to cast a non-numeric value as a float.  You can find the values causing the error with `select distinct num from ... where to_number(num) is null`.